# Will existing indexes be affected when changing character_set and collation of MySQL db

Tags: mysql, database, character-encoding, collation, character-set

1. We have an database where the default character set for tables and columns is set to **utf8** encoding
2. But with character set encoding of **utf8** , we are unable to save emojis
3. To support saving of emojis, 
      a) We had to change the character set of table and columns to **utf8mb4**
      b) We had to change the collation of table and columns to utf8mb4_unicode_ci
      c) Update our JDBC driver so that it supports the unicode encoding

With the above changes we are able to save the emoji in our columns.

**Question:**
1) Do I need to delete existing indexes (varchar columns) and recreate the indexes as earlier with utf8 each character used to take 3 bytes and now with utf8mb4 encoding it will occupy 4 bytes ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An index is an ordered list of pointers to the rows of the table.  The ordering is based on both the `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` of the column(s) of the index.  If you change either, the index must be rebuilt.  A "pointer" (in this context) is a copy of the `PRIMARY KEY`.

You should do one or the other of

```
ALTER TABLE tbl CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE ...,;
```

which converts all the text columns in the table.  Or, if you need to leave some with their current charset/collation, then change each column:

```
ALTER TABLE tbl MODIFY col_name ... CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE ...;
```

where the first '...' is the rest of the column definition (VARCHAR, NOT NULL, whatever).

Any indexes that involve the columns being changed will be rebuilt.  In particular, note that a `VARCHAR` `PRIMARY KEY` is effectively in each secondary index.

The collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` is rather old; you might prefer `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`, especially since it handles Emoji as being distinct rather than lumped together (IIRC).

The fact that utf8 is a subset of utf8mb4 is not relevant; MySQL sees it as a change and fails to take any short cuts.